# Media library management and video bookmarks

Tags: software-recommendation, media

I am looking for a media library management software which will allow me to:

1. Edit video/audio tags
2. Add video/audio bookmarks, like:

   - Name: Shutter Island
   - Time: 1:41:43
   - Comment: Lighthouse encounter scene
3. Search among the database, including tags and (possibly) bookmarks
4. Jump from one bookmark to another just like you would in a web browser

Also, it would be great to have a decent associated media player, possibly with time stretch and AB-repeat (but maybe I'm asking too much).

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 (but I have no problem upgrading, if needed).

Answer (score 1):

[VLC Media Player](http://videolan.org) is able to do `1.` and `2.`. When you show the video/audio track in the playlist, right click on it and then click on "`Information`" (4th option from the top). A popup to edit the track datas (name, comment, album, artist...) will be displayed.

For `3.`, [Clementine Media Player](http://clementine-player.org/) can do that for audio files. It gets search capabilities for this. It can also edit audio files (`1.` and `2.`). For this, right click on an audio track, and then click on "`Edit track information`". You can also do this with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> keyboard shortcut. Clementine is also able to complete tags automatically with its tag fetcher. For this, right click on the track and then click on "Fetch tags" (or something like that). You can also use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut for this.

Comment: For VLC, feature `2.` seems [broken](http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_save_bookmarks).